# Why should I use an CATransaction in an animation?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I've found this code snippet:

```
[self setValue:direction forKey:@"currentDirection"];

CAKeyframeAnimation * animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
animation.path = path;
animation.duration = grids * gridWidth / [self speed];
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
animation.delegate = self;
animation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationLinear;
[self addAnimation:animation forKey:@"movement"];
self.position = destination;

[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:_turn_duration]
                                          forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];
eyes.position = eyeDestination;
pupils.position = pupilDestination;
[CATransaction commit];

CGPathRelease(path);
```

What's the point of using the CATransaction here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the duration of the two implicit animations within the transaction to a value different from the duration of the keyframe animation above. The animations inside the transaction will run over `_turn_duration` seconds, while the keyframe animation will run over `grids * gridWidth / [self speed]` seconds.

Comment: So the CAKeyframeAnimation is an animation block?

Comment: No, it's an animation :D An animation is explicitly or implicitly applied to an object. You can group animations together and then explicitly apply them to objects. What you want to do now is spend some time with the Core Animation Programming Guide, particularly starting at the "Animation" chapter and going forward. http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/AnimatingLayers.html